# How to create case-insensitive unique constraint in Google Spanner using GoogleSql?

Tags: unique-constraint, google-cloud-spanner

I want to create case-insensitive unique constraint for a column. But I am not able to figure out exact syntax for that.

I tried with this below ex query but getting syntax error.

```
alter table test_table_user add constraint user_name_unique unique (lower(user_name))
```

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Spanner requires you to create a unique index instead of a unique constraint. `GoogleSQL` does not support creating indexes on expressions, only on columns, but you can create a computed column and then define a unique index on that column. So in your example the solution would be:

```sql
alter table test_table
  add column user_name_lower string(max) as (lower(user_name)) stored;
create unique index idx_test_table_user_name_unique
  on test_table user_name_lower;
```